# Reporting Services 2008 configuration for basic authentication using username and password

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, ssrs

I want to configure Reporting Services 2008 to use a custom defined username and password for access. I read that I must set reporting services to do basic authentication :

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
         <RSWindowsBasic/>
  </AuthenticationTypes>
```

But I didn't find specified a location where I might create usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Reporting Services 2008 uthenticates against the Local Security Authority (LSA). Anything the LSA can authenticate against can be a credential source, but "out of the box" you're talking about local user accounts on the server computer itself, domain user accounts in the domain the server is a member of, and, if there are any, accounts in trusted domains (or trusted Kerberos realms).

(Thanks, MattB, for pointing out that [Reporting Servers 2008 doesn't use IIS anymore](http://blogs.msdn.com/bwelcker/archive/2007/12/04/everybody-why-leave-iis.aspx%0A).)

Comment: is correct except for one thing - by default Reporting Services 2008 does not use IIS - it handles authentication internally. This is a change from previous versions of RS.

Comment: @MattB: Yikes! That shows me for commenting when not having actually used Reporting Services 2008...